# WebJobs SDK 3 Braking on Function Exception

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, webjob, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have an Azure WebJob (.NET Core - SDK 3) that is braking when an execution of queue triggered function fails. I would like this WebJob to behave like others WebJobs (SDK 2 - .NET Framework) I have running on Windows WebApps.

When execution of queue triggered functions fail on WebJobs SDK 2 (Windows WebApp) the message is sent back to queue with DequeueCount incremented and after X times (default is 5) message is sent to `poison` queue. And the WebJob always keeps running.

Is it possible to have same behavior with WebJobs SDK 3? This is an example of described bahavior ([webjobs.ricardogaefke.com](https://webjobs.ricardogaefke.com/)). In this case I needed to use a try/catch and manually send the message to `poison` queue and it is a waste of the power of webjobs (retry is lost this way).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `FunctionExceptionFilterAttribute`. Functions' filters are similar to ASP.NET MVC filters and in my case I can handle error in My WebJob's functions and return a completed `Task` even on error, so the message is sent back to queue with DequeueCount++ (till the limit of dequeues - default is 5).

The final solution can be found at [webjobs.ricardogaefke.com](http://webjobs.ricardogaefke.com/) and there is a `How it works` page with links to GitHub repo, public Azure Pipelines and public Docker registry.